# Compile Error when instantiating classes

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

```
class Hello a where
  method1 :: a -> String
  method1 a = "Hello"  

data World s = World [s]   

instance Hello a => World a where  
  method1 a = "Hello World"
```

I'm getting the following error when I load the code into Haskell:

‘method1’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘World’

Could someone tell me where the error is?

Thanks.

Comment: `World` isn't a class.  Did you instead mean `instance Hello a => Hello (World a) where ...`?

Answer (score 1):

The `instance` doesn't make much sense. An instance is defined on a type. A possible fix is:

```
instance Hello (World a) where
    method1 _ = "Hello World"
```

An `instance` deals with specifying how a type (or a list of types) maps on a class, so if you have a class `C` with parameters `a`, you can specify:

```
class C a where
    foo :: a -> a
```

Now you don't buy much with this, because you have never said which `a`'s are actually applicable for `C`. With `instance` you specify that a given type (these types can be "generic") are applicable to `C`, so next you can say:

```
instance C a where
    foo = id
```

Here you basically say every type `a` (thus all types) are instances of `C`. And that `foo` should be seen as the `id` function.

Sometimes you want to put additional constraints on `a`, `a` should for instance instantiate an other class. For instance with

```
instance (Integral i) => C i where
    foo = (+) 1
```

Here you say that all integral types `i` are instances of `C` with `foo` being defined as the increment function. **Note that you can't simply combine this and the previous instance, because Haskell doesn't know which to pick in that case.**

Or perhaps you meant to define the instance as @bheklilr suggests:

```
instance (Hello a) => Hello (World a) where
    method1 _ = "Hello World"
```